# Split column names in R

Tags: r, regex, split, names

I have a data frame like below.

df:

```
X1.Name    X1.ID  X1.Prac   X1.SCD
```

But, I need to split the column name by dot and display as,

output df:

```
Name   ID   Prac   SCD
```

Comment: names(df) <- sapply(stringr::str_split(names(d),"\\."),`[`,2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `sub`:

```
names(df) <- sub("^[^.]+\\.", "", names(df))
```

### Demo

The regex pattern I used will match everything from the start of the string up to, and including, the first dot.  Then, it replaces that, and only that, with empty string.

```
^      from the start of the string
[^.]+  match one or more characters which are NOT dots
\\.    then match a literal dot
```

We then replace this entire pattern with empty string `""`, i.e. we remove it from the original string.

Comment: It worked. Can you please explain whats inside the quotation marks? "^[^.]+\\.". Just to learn.

Comment: Thanks and appreciate it.